# Refreshing the screen while card switch in sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a screen where the formBase contains all of the dynamically created UI controls. I am using card layout and switching between views. Now it so happened that I have to execute the formBase for each time the card switches (I mean for each time my screen appears).

I have used the beforeshow listeners for form to achieve that. But its not working. Below is my code.

```
var formBase = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        scroll: 'vertical',
        ui: 'round',
        items: [fieldSet, {
            xtype : 'fieldset',
            items : [ item1, item2, item3]
            ]
        }],
         listeners: {
            beforerender: function(ele) {
               console.log(" Screen before render");
               initScreenComps()
            },

            beforeshow: function(ele) {
                console.log(" screen before show");

            }
        }
    });
```

**Edit:1**

I have a viewport.js file, where i have reveal method to change the viewport. here is the below code of Viewport.js. Still it has no effect. pls suggest.

```
MyApp.views.Viewport = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: 'card',
    initComponent: function() {
        Ext.apply(this, {

            items: [
                { xtype: 'MyApp.views.view1', id: 'view1' },
                { xtype: 'MyApp.views.view2', id: 'view2' },
                { xtype: 'MyApp.views.view3', id: 'view3' },
                { xtype: 'MyApp.views.view4', id: 'view4' },
                { xtype: 'MyApp.views.view5', id: 'view5' }             
            ],
        listeners:{
           beforecardswitch:function(newCard, oldCard, index, animated){
                 //do something...
               console.log(" Card switched"  + " New " + newCard + " OLD : " + oldCard + " index + " index);
           }
        }
        }
        );
        MyApp.views.Viewport.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);
    },

    // used for changing view port of application
    reveal: function(target) {      
        this.setActiveItem(MyApp.views[target],{ type: 'slide', direction: 'right' }
        );
    }
});
```

And now i am calling view2 from the controller, on button click event.

```
MyApp.views.viewport.reveal('view2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, it will be best if you use "beforeactivate" or "activate" event listeners for it. These events get fired whenever the card layout sets this item as the active item. So, the code will be like this:

```
var formBase = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        scroll: 'vertical',
        ui: 'round',
        items: [fieldSet, {
            xtype : 'fieldset',
            items : [ item1, item2, item3]
            ]
        }],
         listeners: {
            beforeactivate: function(panel) {
               console.log(" Screen before render");
               initScreenComps()
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Swar..  thanks a lot..  beforeactivate is working when i have used inside Ext.apply..

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for `beforecardswitch` event instead. for example

```
listeners:{
   beforecardswitch:function(newCard, oldCard, index, animated){
 //do something...
   }
}
```

Comment: @illija139.. do i have to use this listener for form? i have tried but no luck.

Comment: You should use this listener in the object you use to switch the views. For example if you use `obj.setActiveItem(1);` then in the `obj` config you should but the listener. Also try listen `cardswitch` event. If both don't work then probably the problem is with how you init the screen components.

Comment: @illija139.. please check the edit1 section. i have done changes as per your suggestion. but no luck. verify once where i am going wrong.

Comment: Here is live example: http://jsfiddle.net/p5K4q/35/   Like I said check what you do in `initScreenComps();` the problem must be there.